# UINavigationController: Title Jumps in Resize Animation

Tags: ipad, ios, animation, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have an ipad app where i would like to hide and show a category list (kind of like the small view in a split view controller), and the main view which contains a UiNavigationController stack.

I would like to resize the UINavigationController view to fill the whole screen when the category list is hidden, and to shrink when i show the list.

I have it working, except the title of the navigation bar immediately jumps to its new offset when setting the frame within an animation begin/commit block.

Any ideas how to stop the jump of the title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this for fixing those jumps in UINavigationBar for title and right button.

```
#import "UINavigationBar+My.h"

@implementation UINavigationBar (My)

- (void)layoutSubviews {
for (id obj in [self subviews]) {
    if ([NSStringFromClass([obj class]) isEqualToString:@"UINavigationItemView"])
        [(UIView *)obj setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
    else if ([NSStringFromClass([obj class]) isEqualToString:@"UIButton"]) {
        if ([(UIButton *)obj center].x < ([self center].x / 2))
            [(UIButton *)obj setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
        else
            [(UIButton *)obj setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin];
    }
}

@end
```

I hope it will help you ;-)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer +1.  You have certainly pointed me in the right direction, but i cant accept your answer the way it is because its hideous! No class checking...will only work if you only have a title and RHS button (i.e. wont cope with back button).  If apple change view order then it will break..etc.  Please submit a more robust solution for answer to be accepted (or i will answer with my own solution)! Cheers :)

Comment: Haha, sure that was hideous! :) It was just a quick fix in my project. Is this better? What is your solution based on?

Comment: Yeah, thats better, accepted!  will post my own also...yours won't cope with back button, and some other possible scenarious, i think.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem recently; I had a subview of the animating view that was jumping immediately to its new position. This was happening because `-layoutSubviews` was being called on that view as a result of me programmatically modifying it before the animation finished. Are you doing something like changing the text of the title or modifying it in some way that would cause `-layoutSubviews` to be called on it?

Comment: I had a situation where a piece of code called `layoutIfNeeded` within `viewWillAppear`. Removing the `layoutIfNeeded` removed the strange animation.

Answer (score 1):

My solution, seems to cope with all scenarios I hit in my app.  Obviously still a bit of a hack, so no guarantees it will always work!

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (Nick)

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        UIView* titleView = nil;
        CGFloat buttonWidths = 0;
        for (UIView* subview in [self subviews]) {

            if ([subview class] == NSClassFromString(@"UINavigationItemView")) {
                if (titleView) {
                    // Exit here - if there is more than one title, probably doing a pop
                    return;
                }
                titleView = subview;
            }
            else if ([subview class] == [UIView class] ||                           // bar button with custom view
                     [subview class] == NSClassFromString(@"UINavigationButton")) { // or ordinary bar button

                buttonWidths += subview.frame.size.width;
                // is it RHS?
                if (subview.frame.origin.x > subview.frame.size.width) {
                    [subview setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin];
                }
                else {
                    [subview setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
                }
            }
            else if ([subview class] == NSClassFromString(@"UINavigationItemButtonView")) {
                // pretty sure this is always the back button
                buttonWidths += subview.frame.size.width;
                [subview setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
            }
        }


        if (titleView) {
            buttonWidths += 20; // seems to be apple indentation
            CGRect rect = titleView.frame;
            if (rect.size.width > self.frame.size.width - buttonWidths) {
                rect.size.width = self.frame.size.width - buttonWidths;
                titleView.frame = rect;
            }

            titleView.center = self.center;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked fine for me when I included `[self.navigationController.navigationBar layoutSubviews]` in the animation block itself.
Here's the code example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                     [self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:newFrame];
                     [self.navigationController.navigationBar layoutSubviews];
                 }];
```

I hope this is somehow helpful.

Comment: it isn't allowed to call ```layoutSubviews```directly